# How to enable Adaptive search in back-office - hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How to enable adaptive search in back-office.
Which all extensions need to be added.
Please explain the steps.
Hybris version used is 2011.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either install it through Recipes, or manual

### Recipes

Adaptive search is part of the following recipes

- b2b_acc
- b2b_acc_plus
- b2c_acc
- b2c_acc_plus
- b2c_b2b_acc

If you are on a more recent version of SAP Commerce, you need to use the cx recipe

### Manual

Alternatively, you can manually add the adaptive search extensions in your localextensions.xml

For adaptive search, the following can be added to your localextensions.xml

- adaptivesearch
- adaptivesearchbackoffice
- adaptivesearchfacades
- adaptivesearchsamplesaddon
- adaptivesearchsolr
- adaptivesearchwebservices

It depends on your needs if you require all of them.

(If you haven't already included the solr search addons, don't forget those as well)

more info on de SAP website https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2105/en-US/cadb26143c6340f6a79a9bbec60f0e3b.html

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below link to know how to enable adaptive search via recipe or via adding required extensions.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2005/en-US/cadb26143c6340f6a79a9bbec60f0e3b.html